# Is it okay to mix tires of the same brand and size, but not same model?

Tags: tires, replace, accent

The the tread on my front tires is visibly worn (not much tread in some areas) on my vehicle, and they need to be replaced.  The back tires are fine, and had been replaced much more recently due to a chunk being taken out of one of them.

The model of tire of the back tires (HANKOOK OPTIMO H724, P175 / 70R14 - 84T) is no longer available for me to purchase. However, a similar tire, the (Hankook Kinergy S Touring H735 - 175/70R14 84T) is.

Is it safe to replace both front tires and rotate with these two different models of tire?

Comment: Depends on the car. If it is an AWD, or some sub-version of that, probably not a good idea. Other than that, go for it. An honest and qualified shop will tell you this, and they'll happily sell you only two tires if you only need two tires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be absolutely no issues doing as you are suggesting. It happens all the time where tire companies will discontinue one model and have a follow-on of a different one to replace it. Considering they are of the same size and of the same general makeup, there should really be no issue. If you are replacing two, you probably want those two to remain on the same axle (ie: front end or rear end). That way there won't be any subtle size differences due to wear which might lead to some weird behavior.